Adding two layered boxes to give it a stacked box appearance in a mermaid flowchart
I'm trying to use mermaid to create a flowchart but I want to add a couple of more boxes under D to give it a stacked appearance like shown here.
This is what I've used to create the flowchart:
flowchart LR
    A-->D
    B-->D
    C-->D
    D-->E
    E-->F
    F-->G


flowchart LR
A-->D
B-->D
C-->D
subgraph stackD
D1[D1]
D2[D2]
end
D1-->E
D2-->E
E-->F
F-->G

@BGPHiJACK thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it's created something totally different than what was intended.

I'm useless then been too long sir.

It is not possible to achieve the effect you are looking for with mermaidJs

The "stacked" effect is not possible in using Mermaid as of June 2024, sadly.
I had the same question. I tried everything (including subgraphs) and asking on their official Discord. Hopefully they add this in the future.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear and looks like a comment. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked.
